# Authentication page back button

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I'm creating a feature that will help users to log SalesForce using my app. This is the code i'm using to load the authentication page:

```
- (IBAction)salesForce:(UIButton*)sender {

    [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].oauthClientId = kSFOAuthConsumerKey;
    [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].oauthCompletionUrl = kSFOAuthRedirectURI;
    [SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance].scopes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"api",@"custom_permissions",@"web",@"full",@"refresh_token", nil];

    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] addDelegate:self];
    [[SFUserAccountManager sharedInstance] addDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    __weak LeftMenuViewController *weakSelf = self;
    self.initialLoginSuccessBlock = ^(SFOAuthInfo *info) {
        [userDefaults setObject:@(1) forKey:IS_CONNECTED_TO_SALESFORCE];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        [weakSelf loadSalesForceContacts];
    };
    self.initialLoginFailureBlock = ^(SFOAuthInfo *info, NSError *error) {
        [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] logout];
        [userDefaults setObject:@(0) forKey:IS_CONNECTED_TO_SALESFORCE];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    };

    [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:self.initialLoginSuccessBlock failure:self.initialLoginFailureBlock];

}
```

Up until here everything works perfect.

THE ISSUE:
The authentication page doesn't have a back/cancel button.

So I managed to put a button on top of the webView, but I don't know what function this button should call? I've tried all sorts of logout and stuff like that but it gets me back to a frozen app...

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView) documentation. You're probably looking for `canGoBack` and `goBack`.

Of course, much like on the desktop web, going back during the auth process is likely to resubmit forms and potentially get into an awkward state.

**Edit**: I think more useful than a back button on your auth form would be a reload button.

Comment: But i'm not looking to goBack on the webView itself. I'm looking to completely remove the webView and goBack to the last page on my app...

Comment: That depends entirely on your app's view hierarchy. If you're using a `UINavigationController`, you could pop to the parent root view controller. If you added the login page as a child view controller, you can remove it with `removeFromParentViewController`. I can't say more without knowing how your app is built.